# GeoServer S3 Support for GeoTIFF REST-API

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I am stuck with S3 Support for GeoTIFF while I add a dataset with the REST-API.

I did not find any documentation for the REST-API... so I tried to edit my local API-POST-Call:

```
<coverageStore>
  <name>NameOrtho</name>
  <workspace>NameWorkspace</workspace>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <type>GeoTIFF</type>
  <url>s3://bucket/DEM.tif?useAnon=true&awsRegion=EU_CENTRAL_1</url>
</coverageStore>
```

But this returns:

```
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException
cause-message       : 
class               : java.lang.String
required-type       : java.lang.String
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.SingleValueConverterWrapper
wrapped-converter   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.StringConverter
line number         : 6
class[1]            : org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl
converter-type[1]   : org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister$StoreInfoConverter
version             : 2.15.0
-------------------------------
```

What should I do?

Comment: did you look at https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/latest/en/api/1.0.0/coveragestores.yaml

Comment: yes of course, I use /workspaces/{workspace}/coveragestores/{store} for adding my local data and it works...

Comment: I'm confused about your comment about not finding any documentation then - may be you could add the endpoints you are using and the full response (and the log file entry) when it goes wrong

Comment: I mean a documentation if the "S3 Support for GeoTIFF" can used with the REST-API.
The general documentation I found.

Comment: Can you please mention the link for REST api for S3 plugin. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by replacing the `&` in the S3 url with `&amp;`, so my URL ended up looking like this:

`<url>s3://bucket/DEM.tif?useAnon=true&amp;awsRegion=EU_CENTRAL_1</url>`

The `&` character starts an XML entity, which is terminated by `;`. As there is no `;` in the original url, the parser encounters the `=`, which is not a valid character in an entity name.